# Grouping command substitution variables into a subshell to run in background

Tags: bash

I have a group of variables that take a while to load and i want to run them  in the background but it renders the variables as null. This method works for everything except command substitution variables. I understand command substitution is already a sub shell but i need to group them and run them together so i know when the group is done loading.

```
(Update=$(apt-get update && echo updated);
 Upgrade=$(apt-get upgrade && echo upgraded)) &
echo $Update 
echo $Upgrade
```

The variables are empty.

Whats the proper way of grouping these to get a single pid when a background process finishes.

Comment: So don't use environment variables to share the information. Use a file. `echo updated > /tmp/somefile`. Then just `if grep -q updated /tmp/somefile; then echo It updated; fi`.

Comment: Why do you want to save the output in the variables to begin with? Why not just `(apt-get update && apt-get upgrade) & ; agpid=$!` to grab the `pid` of the backgrounded process, then you can do something like `while ps --no-header $agpid ; do sleep .5; done; echo "update done!"` to find out when it is done? You may want to include the `-y` option on the `upgrade` command to allow it to complete without prompting.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you just want to wait until the commands are done you should simply run them in the foreground.

Comment: Im using loading animations for tasks and between tasks i have a huge group of variables that lags the theatrics of the script. Im trying make an additional loading animation for the the lag between tasks created by the variables. As of now you see loading animations then when the script gets to the group of variables it pauses and to a new user of the script it may appear as if sonethings wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First, when putting commands inside parentheses they are run in a [subshell](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell), so the variables are never assigned in the outer scope.

Second, you can't set variables in the background at all:

```
$ foo=bar &
[1] 17621
[1]+  Done                    foo=bar
$ echo $foo
[empty line]
```

Third, running `(apt-get update && apt-get upgrade) &` should allow you to [do other things before `wait`ing for them to finish](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).